# Group Theory: Solvable groups and commutators

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

Question :

Show that a group G is solvable if and only if there exist sub-groups $G^{(0)}$, $G^{(1)}$, ..., $G^{(m)}$, with m $\ge$ 1, such that :

$G^{(m)}$ = {$e_G$} and the $G^{(i)}$ are defined inductively by $G^{(0)}$ = G, and $G^{(i)}$ = [$G^{(i-1)}$, $G^{(i-1)}$], where

[G, G] = < [x, y] | x, y ∈ G, [x, y] = xy$x^{-1}$$y^{-1}$ >

I'm able to show the forward implication, but not the backward one (i.e. the $G^{(i)}$ exist ==> G solvable). I have tried by induction on the i, but this doesn't seem to go anywhere. More specifically, I believe that once $G^{(i-1)}$/$G^{(i)}$ is abelian for all i, the normality $G^{(i)}$ $\lhd$ $G^{(i-1)}$ should be straightforward.

Is this the right approach? How can I show that $G^{(i-1)}$/$G^{(i)}$ is abelian?

Comment: The definition I've been taught has the conditions you mentioned + (−1)/ () has to be abelian and () ⊲ (−1) for all i. Those two conditions are what I'm having difficulty to prove

Comment: $G$ is solvable iff $G^{(n)}=e$ for some $n$. This has been proved at this site several times.